# How to check box in Capybara if there are no name, id or label text?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am newbie here. Please advise. How to select checkbox in my case?

```
<ul class="phrases-list" style="">
<li>
<input type="checkbox" class="select-phrase">
<span class="prase-title"> Dog - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia </span>
<a href="en.wikipedia.org">(en.wikipedia.org)</a>
<div class="prase-desc hidden">The domestic dog (Canis lupus familiaris or Canis familiaris) is a domesticated...</div>
</li>
```

The following doesn't work for me:

```
When /I check box "([^\"]+)"$/ do |label|
      page.check(label)
end
```

step: And I check box "Dog - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the html, wrap the input and span in a label element

```
<ul class="phrases-list" style="">
<li>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-phrase">
    <span class="prase-title"> Dog - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia </span>
  </label>
  <a href="en.wikipedia.org">(en.wikipedia.org)</a>
  <div class="prase-desc hidden">The domestic dog (Canis lupus familiaris or Canis familiaris) is a domesticated...</div>
</li>
```

which has the added benefit of clicks on the "Dog - Wikipedia ..." text triggering the checkbox too.  With that change your step should work as written.  If you can't modify the html then things get more difficult.
Something like

```
find('span', text: label).find(:xpath, './preceding-sibling::input').set(true)
```

should work, although I'm curious how you're using these checkboxes from JS with nothing tying them to any specific value

Comment: Thank you! I just was wondering if there is some workaround (without changing html) . But it is better to change for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you are prevented from changing the HTML.  In this case, it would probably be easiest to query for the element via [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp).  For example:

```
# Here's the XPath query
q = "//span[contains(text(), 'Dog - Wikipedia')]/preceding-sibling::input"

# Use the query to find the checkbox.  Then, check the checkbox.
page.find(:xpath, q).set(true)
```

Okay - it's not as bad as it looks!  Let's analyze this XPath so we can understand what it's doing:

```
//span
```

This first part says "Search the entire HTML document and discover all "span" elements.  Of course, there are probably a LOT of "span" elements in the HTML document, so we'll need to restrict this:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Dog - Wikipedia')]
```

Now we're only searching for the "span" elements that contain the text "Dog - Wikipedia".  Presumably, this text will uniquely identify the desired "span" element on the page (if not, then just search for more of the text).

At this point, we have the "span" element that is adjacent to the desired "input" element.  So, we can query for the "input" element using the "preceding-sibling::" [XPath Axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes):

```
//span[contains(text(), 'Dog - Wikipedia')]/preceding-sibling::input
```